# Not getting a sorted list in python

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x

I have a list of process objects(user-defined) that I want to sort to get the most memory-intensive processes at a time.

But reverse-sorting through the **sorted** is not yielding the required result.

My code:

```
import psutil as pu
import time

class proc:

    def __init__(self,pid,pname,pmem):
        self.pid = pid
        self.pname = pname
        self.pmem = int(pmem)

    # def __lt__(self,other):
    #   return self.pmem<other.pmem

    # def __repr__(self):
    #   return str(self.pmem)+"\t"+self.pname

if __name__ == "__main__":

    meg = 1024*1024
    gig = meg*1024

    while True:
        print(pu.cpu_count())
        print(pu.cpu_percent())
        print("{:.3f} GB".format(pu.virtual_memory().used/gig))
        x = []
        for p in pu.pids():
            pro = pu.Process(pid=p)
            # print(pro.memory_info()[0])
            # print(pro.memory_info()[1])
            x.append(proc(pid=p,pname=pro.name(),pmem=pro.memory_info()[0]))

        sorted(x,key=lambda x:x.pmem,reverse=True)

        for i in x:
            print(str(i.pmem)+'\t'+i.pname)

        time.sleep(5)
```

Output:

http://pastebin.com/7Pz5Yn7A

Comment: `sorted` *creates a new list*, which you don't assign to anything...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `sort` instead of `sorted`:

```
x.sort(key=lambda item: item.pmem, reverse=True)
```

`sort` sorts existing list; `sorted` creates a new one.

Comment: @goelakash, you should be doing `x=sorted(x,.....)` then since _`sorted` creates a new list_.

Comment: Thanks, got it confused with sort from C++ ;)